# When two Excel workbooks are open, each with VBA code, how do I switch the code view between workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel workbooks, each with VBA code. However, the code window (in response to Alt-F11) only displays the VBA code associated with one workbook.  I tried entering Alt-F11 again but, while the label at the top of the code window toggles between my two different spreadsheets file, only one spreadsheet's code is ever displayed.

I tried clicking all of the items in the Project window on the left side (those items related to the non-appearing code), but that didn't help.

Short of closing down one of the spreadsheets, is there any way to toggle between looking at the VBA code for two different, active spreadsheets?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to double-click in the Project explorer - single-click doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either double click on the project explorer, or click in an element with the right button and choose "Display code". It should work.

Comment: Double-clicking in the Project Explorer didn't change anything, at least on my computer.  Right-clicking on the top-level item (labeled "VBAProject(<name of spreadsheet>)" had the "View Code" option grayed out on both spreadsheets.

However, if I right-click on the item highlighted below, I did get the "View Code" option:

         VBAProject(<name of spreadsheet>)
             Modules
                Module1  <----------------

For my two spreadsheets, each with a "VBAProject(..)" header, this allowed me to toggle between the code.

Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: P.S. This is my first post to stackoverflow, let me know if I'm not replying correctly.

Comment: Well, I see one problem.  My use of SHIFT-ENTER to add line breaks to my first comment didn't work, that's why all of my lines are jumbled together.  I was attempting to present a 3-level hierarchy of part of what Project Explorer was displaying.  It looked fine when I edited it, but it all got jumbled together when I was done.

Comment: No problem, I think comments remove Shift-enter. What you described about being grayed out in the title, but avaliable in the rest, is exactly how it should work. Just odd that the double click is not working, first time I heard of this. You know you have to double click the element, not the project name, right? For example, double click in "Module1", not in VBAProject(<name of spreadsheet>) . And you are replying correctly. Just don't forget, if the question is solved, to mark it as solved by chosing an answer.